# CCS, 3 second timer

Tags: c, pic

I want to set a timer for 3 seconds. So that the program will follow a instruction for 3 seconds and then afterwards follow some other instruction set. 20MHz, PIC 16F877A.

Answer (score 2):

There is an example on the [CCS web page](http://www.ccsinfo.com/content.php?page=compexamples#top) called 'Seconds Timer' for your exact same PIC and Clock.

Resuming:

1-You'll need to set the clock in the fuses

```
#fuses HS
#use delay(clock=20000000)
```

2-Write a function for the interrupt handler

```
#INT_RTCC                                    //Interrupt procedure
clock_isr() {                                //called every time RTCC
                                             //flips from 255 to 0
   ///TODO
}
```

3-Initialize the interrupt

```
setup_timer_0( RTCC_INTERNAL | RTCC_DIV_256 );
set_timer0(0);
enable_interrupts(INT_RTCC);
enable_interrupts(GLOBAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

delay_ms(time at nano sec);

example :

```
 delay_ms(1000);  //wait for 1 sec
```

Comment: This will stop the PIC from doing other things, so, it shouldn't fit user needs.